# Declare a global integer in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, int, global

I am trying to declare the int

```
 private int i = 15 - textBox1.Text.Length;
```

as a global integer for this code

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            i = 15 - textBox1.Text.Length;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private int i = 15 - textBox1.Text.Length; //this wont work but i need it to
    private int y = 15 - textBox1.Text.Length; //this wont work either but i also need it to
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (i <= 11)
        {
            i++;
            string ping = new string(' ', i) + textBox1.Text;
            label1.Text = ping;
            if (i == 10)
            {
                y = 11;
            }
        }
        else if (y > 0)
        {
            y--;
            string pong = new string(' ', y) + textBox1.Text;
            label1.Text = pong;
            if (y == 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

but i get the error

A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'text_test.Form1.textBox1'

help?

Comment: From what I can tell, you have a `TextBox`, a `CheckBox`, and a `Label` on a form, and when you check the checkbox, you want a `Timer` to animate the text of the label.  Am I right so far?  What do you want to have happen when the user edits the value in the textbox while the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the *initial* value of the variable `i` (which is a bad variable name, by the way -- variable names should be descriptive!).

You'll need to set the value of `i` at some point in your workflow -- without any context, I'd guess probably in an `OnTextChange` event or something similar.

Comment: the problem is i have to get the text length before i can do what i want because i need to use it in a timer and if i declare it inside of the timer_tick it screws it up

Comment: @IanLundberg I'd recommend posting a new question with more complete code, then. There's probably a more appropriate way to accomplish what you want, but I don't think anyone is going to be able to point you in the right direction without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int i;
```

then after that (in the constructor function or something) do

```
i = textBox1.Text.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the order in which code runs.  You put the field declaration in the middle of your code, perhaps hoping that it would get initialized *after* the checkBox1_CheckedChanged() method runs.  But no, fields are initialized *before* the constructor of the class runs.

That could never come to a good end.  The textBox1 object doesn't exist yet, it gets created by the constructor in the InitializeComponent() method.  It will most certainly not have a Length yet, that won't happen until *much* later when the user types something.  The compiler error keeps you out of trouble.

I have no idea what the code tries to do.  But assuming the `i` variable needs to be initialized with something, you do so when the user types something in the text box.  Which makes the Text.Length property change.  Add an event handler for the textbox' TextChanged event:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 15) {
            i = 15 - textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: will doing that make the value of i stay the same even if i used it in a timer? that is all i need i need i = 15 - textbox1.text.length to be global is there any way of doing that? i have to be able to use it in a timer if i put int i = 15 - textbox1.text.length in the timer it messes it up because each time it ticks it just sets the the value back to that